# dyld library not loaded

Tags: debian, scp, beagleboneblack

I'm having an error while trying to secure copy a file from a Beaglebone connected to my laptop.

```
scp filename username@IP:/Users/username/Desktop/
The authenticity of host '192.168.7.1 (192.168.7.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:secret.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.7.1' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Password:
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/pcre2/lib/libpcre2-32.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/fish
  Reason: image not found
lost connection
```

Architecture details are:

```
uname -a
Linux bealgebone 4.9.45-ti-r57 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 25 22:58:38 UTC 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Any clue what is causing this error? Most searches land in macOS for Ruby which is not what I am using.

Comment: Does the `fish` shell work when you start a terminal on the macOS machine?